# String values left out of PropertyInfo.GetValue

Tags: vb.net, reflection

I am not very well-versed in Reflection, but I have been working on this bit of code for a few days trying to obtain the values of class properties. I am using an API to find the values inside of cron jobs managed by the program VisualCron.

I'll explain the structure a bit. Each cron job has several tasks inside of it which have their own settings. The settings are stored in properties inside the TaskClass class that are declared like so:

```
Public Property <propertyname> As <classname>
```

Each property is tied to its own class, so for instance there is an Execute property inside TaskClass which is declared like this:

```
Public Property Execute As TaskExecuteClass
```

Inside TaskExecuteClass are the properties that hold the values I need. With the below block of code I have been able to retrieve the property values of all types EXCEPT strings. Coincidentally, the string values are the only values I need to get.

I know there must be something wrong with what I've written causing this because I can't find anyone with a similar issue after lots and lots of searching. Can anyone help me please?

```
Dim strAdd As String = ""
For Each t As VisualCronAPI.Server In vcClient.Servers.GetAll()
  For Each f As VisualCron.JobClass In t.Jobs.GetAll
    For Each s As VisualCron.TaskClass In f.Tasks
      Dim propVal As Object
      Dim propInfo As PropertyInfo() = s.GetType().GetProperties()
      For i As Integer = 0 To propInfo.Length - 1
        With propInfo(i)
          If s.TaskType.ToString = propInfo(i).Name.ToString Then
            Dim asm As Assembly = Assembly.Load("VisualCron")
            Dim typeName As String = String.Format("VisualCron.{0}", propInfo(i).PropertyType.Name)
            Dim tp As Type = asm.GetType(typeName)
            Dim construct As ConstructorInfo = tp.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes)
            Dim classInst As Object = construct.Invoke(Nothing)
            Dim classProps As PropertyInfo() = classInst.GetType().GetProperties()
            For h As Integer = 0 To classProps.Length - 1
              With classProps(h)
                If .GetIndexParameters().Length = 0 Then
                  propVal = .GetValue(classInst, Nothing)
                  If Not propVal Is Nothing Then
                    strAdd = f.Name & " - " & s.Name & " - " & .Name & " - " & propVal.ToString
                  End If
                End If
                If strAdd <> "" Then
                  ListBox1.Items.Add(strAdd)
                End If
              End With
            Next
          End If
        End With
      Next
    Next s
  Next f
Next t
```

Comment: Can you show the definition of one of the task classes you are working with, including the strings?

Comment: @ChrisDunaway I am sorry, what exactly does a definition entail? List of properties and their types?

Comment: I was wondering what TaskClass looked like.  Are the strings that are missing declared as public?  Are you certain they are properties and not just fields?

Comment: @ChrisDunaway Oh, sorry. TaskClass has properties that are declared as Public Property, so for the Execute property it is declared as `Public Property Execute As TaskExecuteClass`. The properties inside TaskExecuteClass are the ones that I need and the string values inside of it are the ones I cannot get to. A string value property inside of TaskExecuteClass that I need is declared as `Public Property CmdLine As String`. They are all structured like this and I'm certain they are all properties (at least that's what the API documentation says :-P).

Comment: I was grasping at straws trying to figure out what might be happening.  The code you posted seemed reasonable enough.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway I honestly have no idea what the issue was. I'm learning as I go with this project right now, which is almost complete but now I am running into issues with setting the property value after I've isolated it. Reflection just won't let me win!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my own problem, albeit in a crappy way. This is probably incredibly inefficient, but speed isn't a necessity in my particular case. Here is the code that works:

```
Dim strAdd As String = ""
For Each t As VisualCronAPI.Server In vcClient.Servers.GetAll()
  For Each f As VisualCron.JobClass In t.Jobs.GetAll
    For Each s As VisualCron.TaskClass In f.Tasks
      Dim propVal As Object
      Dim propInfo As PropertyInfo() = s.GetType().GetProperties()
      For i As Integer = 0 To propInfo.Length - 1
        With propInfo(i)
          If s.TaskType.ToString = propInfo(i).Name.ToString Then
            Dim asm As Assembly = Assembly.Load("VisualCron")
            Dim typeName As String = String.Format("VisualCron.{0}", propInfo(i).PropertyType.Name)
            Dim tp As Type = asm.GetType(typeName)
            Dim construct As ConstructorInfo = tp.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes)
            Dim classInst As Object = construct.Invoke(Nothing)
            Dim classProps As PropertyInfo() = classInst.GetType().GetProperties()
            For h As Integer = 0 To classProps.Length - 1
              With classProps(h)
                If .GetIndexParameters().Length = 0 Then
                  propVal = .GetValue(CallByName(s, propInfo(i).Name.ToString, [Get]), Nothing)
                  If Not propVal Is Nothing Then
                    If propVal.ToString.Contains("\\server\") Or propVal.ToString.Contains("\\SERVER\") Then
                      strAdd = f.Name & " - " & s.Name & " - " & .Name & " - " & propVal.ToString
                      ListBox1.Items.Add(strAdd)
                    End If
                  End If
                End If
              End With
            Next
          End If
        End With
      Next
    Next s
  Next f
Next t
```

The piece of code that made the difference was the

```
classProps(h).GetValue(CallByName(s, propInfo(i).Name.ToString, [Get]), Nothing)
```

line.

If there are any suggestions for improving this code - I'm assuming that I've still got a lot of mistakes in here - then please comment for the future viewers of this answer and so I can adjust my code and learn more about how all of this works.